# C - How to use halfdelay(i) in the ncurses library

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I am trying to create a snake game in C using the ncurses library. I would like my program to detect user input at a constant tick speed. If there is no input after a certain amount of time I would like my program to continue along (ie. update game).

This is what I wrote to test out the halfdelay(i) function:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    halfdelay(5);
    
    int user_input;

    do
    {
        user_input = getch();

        if (user_input != -1)
        {
            clear();
            printw("Key pressed: %d\n", user_input);
        }
        else
        {
            //printf("Timeout.\n");  
            printw("Timeout.\n");
        }
    } while (user_input != ESC);

    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT #1:
[I would like to see

Timeout.

Timeout.

Timeout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crbIl.png)


Code used:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    halfdelay(5);

int in;

    do
    {
        timeout(1);
        in = getch();

        if (in != -1)
        {
            clear();
            printw("Key pressed: %d\n", in);
        }
        else
        {
            //printf("Timeout.\n");  
            printw("Timeout.\n");
        }

        refresh();
    } while (in != 27);

    endwin();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Whatever you end up pasting for your test, please do your best to make it a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a specific problem that you indicate.

Comment: @JeffHolt Thanks, I cleaned it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some history first.

Traditionally, the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key value has been used as the prefix for [*escape sequences*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence), which denote special sequences of characters that can be interpreted as a non-graphic character (e.g., an arrow key, a function key, etc.)

Due to *(n)curses* focus on portability (and telecommunication), out of the box it supports this notion of escape sequences, and as such pressing the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key can have some side effects. Notably, when `keypad` is enabled, there is an inbuilt delay as the program waits to decide if the user simply pressed <kbd>ESC</kbd> or if it needs to wait for some more information to complete the escape sequence. This timing can be adjusted via the `ESCDELAY` environment variable, or the `set_escdelay` function.

All this is important as you work forward, as given its a game you may want to enable the functionality of the `keypad` eventually, which will create some extra steps when using the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.

And because of all this, there is no `ESC` or `KEY_ESC` macro for for the escape key. Instead, its raw code is `27` (or the octal `033`).

Your use of the `halfdelay` function seems perfectly fine to me, just know that the argument is in *tenths of a second*, so `5` is half a second. Tenths of a second may not achieve the desired effect in a game, so consider using the `timeout` function instead, which allows for higher precision.

A simple, working example:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void) {
    initscr();
    halfdelay(5);
    
    int user_input;
    
    while ((user_input = getch()) != 27) {                
        clear();                                     
                                                     
        if (user_input == ERR)
            printw("Timeout.");
        else
            printw("Key pressed: %d\n", user_input);                                                                  
                                                                                                                      
        refresh();                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                      
    endwin();                                                                                                         
}
```

---

Your updated program "works", it just doesn't clear the screen properly. Note that you probably don't want to mix calls to `printw` and `printf` as it creates a strange mess of the screen.

Also, you should use `halfdelay` *or* `timeout`, but not both. Remember that `timeout` takes its argument in *milliseconds*, which is 1/1000 of a second, and it sets the blocking delay for a *window* (`timeout` for `stdscr`, `wtimeout` for specific windows). It's not a "sleep" style function.

Use one delay function at a time, move `clear` to outside the `if` statement, and use `printw`. This is functionally the same program to the one posted above, just with a `do ... while` loop.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void) {
    initscr();
    /*
    noecho();
    scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);
    */
    timeout(500);
                   
    int in;        

    do {
        in = getch();
        
        clear();
        
        if (in != ERR)
            printw("Key pressed: %d\n", in);
        else
            printw("Timeout.\n");
        
        refresh();
    } while (in != 27);

    endwin();
}
```

If you are expecting the display of this program to be something along the lines of

```
Timeout.
Timeout.
Key pressed: 65
Timeout.
...
```

like a more traditional terminal, then you simply want to remove `clear` all together, and un-comment `noecho` and `scrollok`.

Comment: Thanks! I actually defined ESC in a header file and I forgot to change it to 27 on my example program. I am trying timeout() now.

Comment: I have tested your program and I also created one with the timeout() function, but it still does not seem to work. I will attach what I created in my original post.

Comment: @Daniel See updated answer, as I'm pretty sure that one of those options should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! That printf was the problem, I overlooked it.